# How to run a function inside of a function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having a small issue on running a function inside of a function. Hope u guys can guide me.

```
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction()
{
    function play(a, b)
    {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = a * b;
    }
}

myFunction().play(2,3);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you need to return your `inner function` `play`

Comment: how do i do that

Comment: To call like this `myFunction().play(2,3);` you need to return object that has `play` method in it.

Answer (score 3):

To keep with your current usage, try this:

```
function myFunction()
{
    return {
        play: function(a, b)
        {
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = a * b;
        }
    }
}

myFunction().play(2,3);
```

Answer (score 0):

So what you've done with `myFunction` is nested a 'private' function `play` inside so the outside cannot call it. So you can either return the inner function or **call** play inside of function like and only call `myFunction`:

```
function myFunction(a, b) {
    function play(a, b) {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = a * b;
    }
    play(a, b);
}
myFunction(2,3); // will set innerHTML of demo to a*b
```

Or remove the nesting and just have

```
function play(a, b) {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = a * b;
}
play(2,3);
```

Comment: my aim to allow the function play to take values only and i'll be adding numerous other private function in them so this method I think wont be suitable

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to access the play function where you are currently invoking. The play function is out of scope.

```
function myFunction()
{
    function play(a, b)
    {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = a * b;
    }

    play(2,3);
}

myFunction()
```

This should work for you

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this because that function `play` only exists within the function `myFunction` and everything outside of it won't be able to execute it.

An alternative is to return an object with a property called `play` whose value is the function you need to execute.

```js
function myFunction() {
  return {
    play: function(a, b) {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = a * b;
    }
  }
}

myFunction().play(2, 3);
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```